# How can I see the resolution of images in a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I got a 200 MB PDF with just a 6x4" picture in it. I am curious to see how many DPI it has been scanned, but if I open it in Photoshop, it asks me to render it again, so it won't be the original data.

So how I can get information about the images embedded in the PDF?

Comment: Moreover, images in a PDF are all encoded in JPG, right? I think this guy scanned at 9600 DPI "because it's better quality"

Comment: [Related answer](https://superuser.com/q/1241248)

Comment: @Danielillo but that requires Acrobat Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to Check DPI of Images in PDF's with Photoshop

1. Open your PDF with Photoshop, then select **Images** and choose the image you want to check.

[image]

2. Now press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+i</kbd>

[image]

3. The resolution used is now shown in the resolution area.

*This will not work if you open multiple images. A PSD can only support one resolution at a time.